Ask interactive user to respond yes or no
I've written a Bash function that can ask a simple yes/no question.

The "yes/no" prompt is translated to the user's language (the question must be localised by the caller).
Input is accepted in the same language.
Language falls back to English if message catalogue is not available.
The question is repeated until a valid response is entered.
One reply may be specified as default if the user just gives an empty string, which is presented in capital letters, as is the convention - or if the language doesn't have uppercase/lowercase distinction, then it's highlighted with [⋯].
If no default is specified, empty input is not valid.
It returns success or failure so it can be used directly as a command in conditionals.
Shellcheck reports no issues.

#!/bin/bash

# ask_with_default message [0|1]
# First argument is the question to ask
# Second argument, if present, is 0 or 1 to default to yes or no, respectively
ask_with_default() {
    local messages true false answer default
    readarray -t messages < <(locale LC_MESSAGES)
    true=${messages[2]:=yes}
    false=${messages[3]:=no}
    default=${2-}
    case "$default" in
        [01])
            local tf=(true false)
            local -n d=${tf[$default]}
            if [ "${d,,}" != "${d^^}" ]
            then
                # upcase the default
                true=${true,,}
                false=${false,,}
                d=${d^^}
            else
                # alt. highlight if upper case is same as lower
                d="[$d]"  # or "$d(*)" etc
            fi
            ;;
        '')
            # no default
            ;;
        *)
            # Invalid, so ignore, with a warning
            echo >&2 "Usage: ask_with_default message [0|1]"
            default=
            ;;
    esac

    while true
    read -rp "$1 ($true/$false) " answer
    do if [[ "$answer" =~ ${messages[0]:=^[yY]} ]]
       then
           return 0
       elif [[ "$answer" =~ ${messages[1]:=^[nN]} ]]
       then
            return 1
       elif ! [ "$answer" ] && [ "$default" ]
       then
            return "$default"
       fi
    done
}

Example usage (I haven't bothered to translate the question here, just for clarity)

if ask_with_default "Is this good?" 0
then
    echo "That makes me happy."
else
    echo "I'm sorry you don't like it."
fi


Here's the yes/no selection in a handful of locales I have available here ():

C: (YES/no)
cy: (IE/na)
gd: (THA/chan eil)
kl: (AAP/naagga)
el: (ΝΑΙ/όχι)
ru_UA: (ДА/нет)
ko: ([예]/아니요)
ja: ([はい]/いいえ)


Concerns

General review of the code - anything that could be clearer, more efficient or in any other way better?
Is the use of [⋯] to highlight the default in non-cased scripts clear and understandable for users?  Or is there an existing convention I could use instead?


I've never seen code like while true<newline>read -rp "$1 ($true/$false) " answer<newline>do with true and read newline-separated between the while and do and would have to write a script of my own to test with to figure out what it does (I'd have expected a syntax error). So maybe there's a clearer way to write whatever that does? Maybe it's the same as while read ...; do or while true; do read ..., or something else, idk.

Yes, the true wasn't meant to be there - see first comment to J_H's review.  Fortunately it's harmless, since the status of true; read is just that of the read.

Nice specs, very solid and bulletproof.
I found the Review Context quite helpful.
Consider putting some of that discussion into the source code.
cryptic syntax

anything that could be clearer

Few people choose to write code using the symbols of Iverson's
APL,
and arguably the Perl one-liner's resemblance to "modem line noise"
led to folks seeking more Algol-like alternatives
with pronounceable syntax.
                # upcase the default
                true=${true,,}
                false=${false,,}
                d=${d^^}

I thank you for the comment.
This is laudably efficient, as we don't fork a child process
for the idiomatic tr "A-Z" "a-z" or tr "a-z" "A-Z".
But as a maintenance engineer I would rather see the tr idiom
than try my luck googling
documentation
for symbols that can pose a challenge to search for.
(spoiler alert: Scroll down to §3.5.3 for the answer,
or in the man page scroll past 1200 lines of technical material.)
The "unix tools" philosophy is to use "small" programs
in a way that will compose nicely.
The Bourne / bash language is no longer small,
and a significant fraction of its features
are accessed via cryptic sigils and symbols.
When you feel the need to write an explanatory comment,
consider writing in a more conservative subset,
taking advantage of additional tools outside the interpreter.
Upon encountering an unfamiliar switch like tr -d,
it's easy to lookup its man page description
since the command is narrowly focused on just one thing.
Minimally, please move the comment so it's immediately above the "upcase" line.
(I do appreciate the attention to local details,
keeping the namespace clean.
And e.g. the :=yes defaulting, =~ regexes, and the echo to stderr
are idiomatic and beautiful.)
nameref
            local -n d=${tf[$default]}

$ help local is unhelpful here,
but $ help declare reveals that this is a name reference,
a feature added to the language just five years ago.
(In contrast the chain for readarray -t was far friendlier.)
So we are altering tf, something that wasn't immediately obvious to me.
Running this on a CentOS bash-4.4 would be unfortunate and
fairly plausible, so consider testing $BASH_VERSINFO.
while forever
    while true
    read -rp "$1 ($true/$false) " answer
    do ...

Wow. Apparently this works, ok.
Users of ALGOL inspired languages routinely use "while foo" statements,
where foo might involve a "(bar, baz)" block to stitch multiple statements
into a larger block.
Here I suppose the newlines act as ; semicolons to do that.
Consulting $ help while reveals "while COMMANDS; do ...",
with plural rather than singular COMMAND.
Thank you for teaching me something.
(On reflection I think this is not the first time I have
encountered this usage. But I wouldn't call it usual.)
Nonetheless, consider rephrasing this more
idiomatically as while read ... || true; do ....
(Though with no edits I confess the meaning of the OP code as-is
will be immediately apparent to any future maintenance engineer
who comes across this, without loss of clarity.)
design of Public API
name
The verb "ask" is certainly accurate if a little vague.
It does not imply "predicate".
ask_with_default() {

Often we will see yorn for such a boolean.
Or pronounced the same but a little more verbosely, y_or_n.
Consider incorporating that into the identifier.
specification


The question is repeated until a valid response is entered.


Thank you for making this explicit.
Suppose that app.sh relies on ask_with_default.
It seems plausible that someone might do cat stock_responses.txt | app.sh,
perhaps as part of a test suite or an installer.
A locale mismatch between the two parts of that pipeline leads to tragedy,
similar to when /usr/bin/yes interacts badly with a sink that
we thought would consume just a fixed number of inputs.
Consider adopting either of these mitigating strategies:

Report "no" (or the default) after a threshold of bad inputs, perhaps a dozen.
Unconditionally sleep 1 when we return none of {0, 1, $default}, for fear of burning up a core.

defaulting
The fact that caller may specify a default or not is kind of interesting,
and makes analysis more complex.
Consider offering a pair of related functions,
with one of them ensuring that there's always a default value.
Which would simplify the yes x | app.sh and app.sh  < /dev/null cases.
(For the immediate EOF case, perhaps app.sh execution is conditional on existence of some file, and so snuck through testing without ever asking a Y/N question, leading to sadness in diverse production environments.)
Alternatively, perhaps you have no "default-free" use cases,
and can safely eliminate that code path.

Is the use of [⋯] to highlight the default ... clear?

Yes, seeing a "[y]/n" prompt is usual and makes for a good UX.

This codebase with associated specification is admirably clear and achieves its design goals.
I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it.

Oh, the while true; read; do was a mistake - the true is obviously redundant there.  It's a cut+paste error: I meant to put the read line after the do.  But perhaps we need to do something when read fails, so perhaps further thought is required there - perhaps exit in that case?

Interestingly, most locales I inspected accept anything beginning +, 1, y or Y for "yes" and anything beginning -, 0, n or N for "no" in addition to the locale-specific values (e.g. the ja_JP "yes" regex is ^([+1yYｙＹ]|はい|ハイ)).  I'm not sure what to expect if the localised "no" begins with y, but I guess that's theoretically possible.

I also noticed "S", presumably for the non-ambiguous "Si". I confess I was a little surprised to find my {default, minimal} Ubuntu server complaining about “no locale file”. It’s a failure mode that hadn’t occurred to me. In part because the locale I tend to specify is C, to avoid utf8 parsing so  that /usr/bin/sort will work quickly.

"if the localised "no" begins with y". I note in passing that in some cultures  horizontal head nodding indicates agreement rather than dissent, which can lead to cross-cultural hilarity and ultimately to better understanding. If only programs could understand!
